# Why isn't iCloud drive icon visible in finder

Tags: macos, icloud, icon

This is more of an aesthetic question rather than a functional one, but after upgrading to OSX Yosemite I don't have the iCloud drive or history icon in finder, it just gives me the default.  In finder preferences, the icons appear normally...Any ideas why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: and it is not in the Finder preferences?

Comment: In finder preferences the icons are there:

Comment: and if you enable it (check mark) it still does not show in Finder side bar?

Comment: reset your finder using alt+cmd+esc then in the pop uo reset (relaunch) the finder.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help.  Correct, as shown, with iCloud Drive and Downloads enabled, it still doesn't show in the finder.  Reseting/relaunching the finder does not have any effect...

Comment: I guess reinstalling Yosemite is the only solution...

Comment: sounds like it :)